# Why the following works in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-2.1, ruby-2.2

`to_a` over a range of integers behaves differently in this case.
Upto 15 decimals, `include?` returns `false` but once it reached 16 decimals array considers the decimal digit as part of array.

> Why?

```
2.2.1 :020 > (1..9).to_a.include?(8.999999999999999)
 => false 
2.2.1 :021 > (1..9).to_a.include?(8.9999999999999999)
 => true 
2.2.1 :022 >
```

> And why **range only** says this is true

```
2.2.1 :001 > (1..9).include?(8.9)
 => true
```

Comment: `(1..9).include?(8.9)` is the same than `1 <= 8.9 && 8.9 <= 9`. I think it is obvious why this returns `true`. But `(1..9).to_a` returns the array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. This leads to the question why does `8.9999999999999999 == 9` eval to `true`, but `8.999999999999999 == 9` to `false`? Floating point shenanigans...

Comment: Yet another ***"why don't numbers work in language x"*** question. xd

Comment: @spickermann, you should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(1..9).include?(8.9)` is the same than `1 <= 8.9 && 8.9 <= 9`. I think it is obvious why this returns `true`.

But `(1..9).to_a` returns the array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. This leads to the another observation:

```
8.999999999999999 == 9   #=> false
8.9999999999999999 == 9  #=> true
```

[Floating point shenanigans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

You might want to use [`next_float`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html#method-i-next_float) to investigate the next representable floating-point number (as Tom Lord pointed out in the comments):

```
8.999999999999999.next_float   #=> 9.0
8.9999999999999999.next_float  #=> 9.000000000000002
```

Et voilà.

Comment: Just to add to this - assuming you are using ruby `v2.2+`, you can use `Float#next_float` to help understand what's happening: `(8.999999999999999).next_float == 9.0; (8.9999999999999999).next_float == 9.000000000000002` - In other words, `8.9999999999999999` is literally the same thing as `9.0` in ruby. Such floating point rounding errors are NOT specific to ruby.

Comment: Yes it is same as 9 when you run 8.9999999999999999 on irb its return 9.0 but when you run 8.999999999999999 it returns 8.999999999999998

Comment: Definitely floating point shenanigans, but remember that a Range is not an Array, so asking why 8.99 is included in `1..9` but not in `(1..9).to_a` is not really possible. Conceptually, `(1..9).to_a` is the same as `(1..9).step(1).to_a`. Take it smaller: `(8.1)..(9.0).to_a` will fail with a `TypeError`, but `(8.1)..(9.0).step(0.1).to_a` will not.